# Database connection failure

Tags: php, mysqli, database-connection

I have recently created a database but for some reason I am not able to connect to it. I have used the same file that I have used many times before but this time it seems there is a problem. Here is the way I connect to my DB:

```
$db_host = "localhost";
$db_name = "some_name";
$db_user = "some_admin";
$db_pass = "some_password"; 

$conn = mysqli_connect($db_host, $db_name, $db_user, $db_pass);
```

I am working on a new version of my website this means that all the files are in a "temporary" folder inside the "public" one. Could this be the issue?

Comment: error message is ??????????

Comment: Warning: mysqli::mysqli(): (HY000/1045):

Comment: thats not the full error message

Comment: I have changed the parameter order as suggested by @ghazi2008 and now there is no message showing...the form sends the email but it can't connect to the DB. Therefor the DB doesn't store the info...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change the parameter order !!

from

```
 $conn = mysqli_connect($db_host, $db_name, $db_user, $db_pass);
```

to

```
$conn = mysqli_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass, $db_name);
```

Comment: I have changed the parameter order and now there is no message showing...the form sends the email but it can't connect to the DB. Therefor the DB doesn't store the info...

Comment: ...sorry it works now...I get the email with all the info and the DB stores the info...I must have made a typo when I did cut and paste of the parameters...thank you!